# Can we pass Date Value like (2/3/2023) to parameter variable that initby expression in stimulsoft?

Tags: c#, datetime, expression, report, stimulsoft

We have variable 'mydate' that has data type as DateTime and that is init by expression.

Can I pass a value like (2/3/2023) to this variable? Or do we have to pass the expression (Today.AddDays(8)) only?

It is working when we pass expression. But it is failing (throwing below error) with the value '2/3/2023'.

```
System.Exception: Compilation error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'System.DateTime'

   at Stimulsoft.Report.StiReport.Compile(String path, Stream stream, StiOutputType outputType, Boolean autoCreate, Object standaloneReportType)
   at Stimulsoft.Report.Engine.StiReportV2Builder.RenderSingleReport(StiReport masterReport, StiRenderState renderState)
   at Stimulsoft.Report.StiReport.RenderReport(StiRenderState renderState)
   at Stimulsoft.Report.StiReport.Render(StiRenderState renderState, StiGuiMode guiMode)
   at Stimulsoft.Report.StiReport.Render(Boolean showProgress)
```

Snapshot for your reference:

[image]

Can someone help why it is not converting 2/3/2023 to DateTime when we pass value?

Comment: Have you tried to cast the date picker output from int to Datetime? 
Something like DateTime.Parse(i.ToString())

Comment: Stimulsoft internally converting this input ('2/2/2023') to DateTime

Comment: I don't have control over this input as this is handled by stimulsoft(third party).

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer from stimulsoft support:

> Hello,
>
> It seems I understand why you get the issue. The date should be in a
> specific format. Our engine can't parse this date.
>
> Please, convert the date to the ISO 8601 format.
>
> Thank you.